# how to get the volume difference between the earliest and latest time in a day?

Tags: dolphindb

create table as below:

```
time = take(10:10:00.300+1..30*300, 200)
tradeMoney = double(take(1..100, 200))
SecurityId = take(`A, 100) join take(`B, 100)
volume = take(1..300, 200)
t = table(time,tradeMoney, SecurityId,volume)
```

table structure as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cShHF.png)

not sure how to get the volume difference between the earliest and latest time in a day and group by SecurityID?

Answer (score 0):

```
select last(volume)-first(volume) as volDiff from t group by SecurityId
```